# Get a list of values from a list of enumerations

Tags: python

Let us assume that we have an enum class:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
```

How to get the list of values `[1, 1, 2]` from the above list of enumerations?

```
mylist = [MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.bar]
```

I know it is possible to create a new list using list comprehension, but I am wondering if there exists a more natural and straighforward way to get the same output.

Comment: What is your definition of "more natural" and "straightforward"? I'm afraid I don't understand your request. What exactly is the problem you try to solve?

Comment: How do you use a list comprehension to do that?

Comment: If you need the integers for further calculations, you could just use an `enum.IntEnum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can access `name` and `value` of an `Enum` class by `.name`, `.value`. So a simple list comprehension could solve your problem.

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
mylist = [MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.bar]
my_enum_val_list = [i.value for i in mylist]
```

Further, you can also use `IntEnum` to make it behaves just like a simple int array.

```
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
mylist = [MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.foo, MyEnum.bar]
```

Comment: Thanks hide1nbush. My question deals with the existence of a more straightforward solution, e.g. coming from the implementation of enumerations in Python.

Comment: @Aleph I'm afraid not. `Enum` is actually stored by a `dict`, which is the same story if you want to access the key or value.

Comment: @Aleph could you please your scenario? Why do you want get the values of `Enum`, maybe there's other solutions.

Comment: Sure, I want to get an output from a function, y = fun(mylist) but it does accept my list of enumerations as an input. The function is the one named "predict" in this page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

Comment: It is not an expected behaviour as this function does not make any computation from the input list. For example, lists of strings are processed correctly.

Comment: @Aleph I have updated the answer. I think `IntEnum` should work for this scenario.

Comment: Wonderful, it works fine! Thanks again for your help hide1nbush.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think about a map:

```py
myvaluelist = list(map(lambda _ : _.value, mylist))
```

however I think it is much less 'natural' than list comprehesion:

```
myvaluelist = [_.value for _ in mylist]
```

[EDIT]
Also comprehesions are quite well optimized, which may be another plus, once one is used to them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
nb_foo=2
nb_bar=1

mylist1=[MyEnum.foo for i in range(nb_foo)]
mylist2=[MyEnum.bar for i in range(nb_bar)]

mylist = mylist1 + mylist2
print(mylist)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2]
```